# Each apple and each orange [has/have]?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, determiners, coordinating-conjunctions

For a phrase such as the following:

> each apple and each orange

Is it correct to use "has" or "have" when describing properties of both apples and oranges?

Comment: I think it is better to avoid the use of 'each' two times.
Each apple and orange "has" been picked from the best orchards of the world.

The same rule is applied to "every" as well!

Comment: @Manjima I don't think it is necessarily better. "Each apple and each orange is treated with the special tenderness it deserves" - remove the second "each" and the sentence's emphasis is altered.

Comment: The meter is altered (ie if spoken), but the emphasis >if reading> is the same.

Comment: @Sherlock: Thanks, I get that-especially when I think of someone speaking these words!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both *each apple* and *each orange* are respectively singular so it has to be **has**.  If *apples and oranges* (plural) were the subject, you could use **have**.

Comment: "Each" is a pronoun?

Comment: yes, can be.  But now that you (didn't) mention it, in this case it looks like it is used an adjective.  I'll correct that.

Comment: does this fall into collective noun usage? ie, when referring to a musical group, one might say 'The Who is a great band' and 'The Who are a great band' and be subject to localized usage rules?

Comment: No, I don't think it does. I think that the style guides on both sides of the pond are united that "each" takes a singular.
I would have said that speakers generally follow this, but Google appears to prove me wrong: "Each of the members has" gets 3m hits, "Each of the members have" gets 33m.

Comment: "Each" is actually a determiner, or more specifically, a quantifier (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification).

Comment: Wait a minute. Both *an apple* and *an orange* are respectively singular, so it has to be *An apple and an orange has*? Something is wrong with the reasoning here. I agree the answer is *has*, but I can't claim to know why.

Comment: _Each_, by definition, creates an enforced separation. _An_ does not. Its only function is to designate one item out of a group, not to isolate that item, as _each_ does. _An apple and an orange_ therefore creates a conjoined subject, which is plural. It is necessary to form the plural this way, because you can't do it by some means such as adding "s," as you can when the items involved are all apples. "Two apples" is plural, and so is "an apple and an orange." The use of _each_ is specifically for the purpose of saying "take the members of this group individually, not as a group."

Answer (score 8):

Let's change *each* to reveal its meaning, and see what happens.

> *Every individual* apple and *every individual* orange

We can now more easily see that *each* refers to the singular nature of one apple, and the singular nature of one orange. But more than that, it emphasizes that *each* of these things stands alone, and functions independently as the subject of the sentence. By using *each* in this way, we prevent the apple and the orange from being linked into a group; the use of *each* in fact *separates* them. Therefore, the verb remains singular, and you would say "has," not "have."

Using *each* in this way is equivalent to separating the two things and constructing an independent clause which we then use for each one, such as in this example:

> An apple has a stem, and an orange has a stem.

Note that I have changed *each* to *an*. I can do this because repeating the independent clause makes it clear that I am referring to only one thing at a time (or one class of things; "an apple" sometimes refers to apples in general). And quite naturally, I use *has* for each clause. We don't usually use this kind of repetition, though, because it is awkward, and that is why the use of *each* is effective, thus: *Each apple and each orange has a stem.* That's more succinct and efficient.

Also note that *an* isn't the only word that can be used in this place; it's just an example. I could have said, "That (or *my* or *one* etc.) apple has a stem, and that (*same options*) orange has a stem." And I could even have used *each*, thus: "Each apple has a stem, and each orange has a stem." In this case, however, the use of *each* is different; here it actually means I am talking about *every one of the whole group of all* the apples. (English allows for lots of subtly different usages of the same word. That's what makes this web site so interesting.)

On the other hand, if I had said "an apple and an orange," (keeping the two things together, and not separating them by sticking a clause in between) this would *link* the two objects into a group, and would create a plural subject for the sentence. You would then say "an apple and an orange have stems." (This would still be referring to apples an oranges as classes of objects, but now the classes are joined into a plural subject.)

So, just to reiterate, in the case of your example, "has" is the correct choice.

6/19/13 ADDENDUM TO RESPOND TO TCHRIST'S QUESTION:

*Each* does in fact change a coinjoined subject into two (or however many you are referencing) singles. But asking why it does so seems to me to be similar to asking why a car transports people from place to place. It does so because that's exactly what it is supposed to do. That is its function. Also, and interestingly, your examples of "both pieces the same" do not quite seem the same to me. "The master and commander" refers to one and the same person, does it not? And yet even in this case, you could put *each* in place, and suddenly you would be referring to two different people. Talk about a separation! In the second example, "time and tide" are two separate entities, and you could separate them with *each* if you chose, but of course I needn't tell you that that would destroy the well known axiom, changing both the poetry and the meaning in a way that wouldn't suit what you are trying to say. And yet, it would be valid syntactically, and would emphasize the *oneness* of each of these entities.

Comment: Isn't it interesting to note that no one else has contributed an answer? Pity. This is practically a two horse race, if we exclude Chris, despite the high number of views and comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have noticed a strong tendency to post a lot of answer level responses as comments. Have you noticed how John Lawler, who I'm sure is the most knowledgeable of us all, seems always to use comments? I never see a formal "answer" from him, although I guess he must have posted plenty in the past. I always like your answers, by the way. And don't you find it ironic that Chris's answer, which was just about as simple as can be imagined, and including minimal explanation, was accepted right away? No offense, Chris, by the way; the succinctness of that answer is a great virtue.

Answer (score -1):

### REVISED

It is clear that apples and oranges are completely different fruits, so we are not talking about a specific *group* of students, political candidates, houses, or countries etc. However, these two fruits do share one quality.

> Each apple has been handpicked with care.

and

> Each orange has been handpicked with care.

Therefore:

> Each apple and each orange **has** been handpicked with care.

The adjective *each* is used when we want to emphasize the singularity of the subject.

1. Each boy ***has*** his own bedroom.
2. Each couple ***is*** going away on holiday. (the word *couple* although made up of two people is considered as a single unit.)
3. Each of the apartments ***has*** (not *have*) its (not *their*) own private entrance (not *entrances*).
   <sub>*[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/each)*</sub>

It is the conjunction "and" which tells us that every apple and orange share this one feature.  It is the adjective, "each", that explicitly tells us which apples and oranges; every single one. Consequently, the verb “have” agrees with the individual fruit (singular subject) thus explaining why "has" and *not* have is preferred.

If the author wishes to use the plural verb, have, for stylistic reasons, nothing forbids him from doing so.  He merely needs to change the wording and reposition the small but very useful word, *each* in the sentence.

> The apples and oranges each **have** been handpicked with care.

Comment: Consider: “That man ***has*** left. That woman ***has*** left. That man ***and*** that woman ***have*** left.”  Why doesn’t the same rule apply with each?

Comment: "each" singles out the subject. We say *each one/person/student* has been given a new text book. We are not talking about a group, or a sum total of people, but every individual. Whereas "that man" and "that woman" are in effect two people and so the verb changes accordingly. (This is me just rationalizing off the top of my head but I will try to do some research to see if my instincts are correct.)

Comment: One of the peculiarities of English quantifiers is that they vary in number. _Each_ and _every_ are both singular, while _all_ is plural. This is true even in conjoined phrases like _each apple and each orange_. It isn't logical, but it is grammatical. If you think this is odd, consider that _nothing_ is singular, when it is clearly neither singular **nor** plural.

Comment: But as I understand it, each apple and each orange are not meant to be totalled, so that's why they take the singular. We have the expressions: *each and every one* and *each single one* to say regardless of how many, I am giving you this piece of significant information. When people say: "all the apples and oranges" they really mean; nearly everyone, very close to all, give or take a few, practically every one, but definitely more than one. (I hope I didn't say anything naive.)

Comment: @JohnLawler tchrist gives as an example to back his argument this sound piece of logic:"Usually two singular subjects joined with “and” demand plural concordance **A man and a woman have come to our door**. But there's no reason why we couldn't say: **"A man has come to the door and a woman has (also) come to the door."** Both subjects are conjoined with "and" and both perform the same action. However, this second reconstruction suggests to me that the man and woman came at different times, whereas in the first phrase we might assume the man and woman came *together*.

Comment: But the question is about _each_, and that's what I was talking about. Normally a conjoined NP is plural, as you say; quantifiers, however, have their own syntax, which overrides a lot of normal constraints. That reconstruction seems reasonable, though it's just one reasonable scenario. Making up such scenarios ("frames" in the trade) is part of how we understand sentences.

Comment: @John Is this then the answer?

Comment: Don't ask me. I'm not the OP.

Comment: @tchrist To your first comment in this section, the same rule does not apply to _each_ because its very purpose, intention, and design, is to negate that rule; it is meant to say, "in this case, do not link these items into a group; consider them as (in some specified way) equivalent single items."